# NestJS TypeORM pagination with many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, database, pagination, nestjs, typeorm

I have method in my product service like the one below.  I'm filtering the data and using nestjs-typeorm-paginate to paginate, but it doesn't work properly (with a page size of 10 it returns 4-5 records depending on the number of related rooms. Without using room relation everything works great)

```
async findAllPaginated(
    options: IPaginationOptions,
    filters?: any,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const queryBuilder = this.productRepository.createQueryBuilder('product');
    queryBuilder.leftJoinAndSelect('product.category', 'category');
    /* Room uses many to many relation */
    queryBuilder.leftJoinAndSelect('product.room', 'room');

    if (filters.category) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere(`category.id like '${filters.category}'`);
    }

    if (filters.room) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere(`room.id like '${filters.room}'`);
    }

    if (filters.priceMin) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere(`product.price >= ${filters.priceMin}`);
    }

    if (filters.priceMax) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere(`product.price <= ${filters.priceMax}`);
    }

    if (filters.promoPriceMin) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere(`product.promoPrice >= ${filters.promoPriceMin}`);
    }

    if (filters.promoPriceMax) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere(`product.promoPrice <= ${filters.promoPriceMax}`);
    }

    if (filters.sortField) {
      queryBuilder.orderBy(filters.sortField, filters.sortDirection);
    }

    return paginate<Product>(queryBuilder, options);
  }
```

Generated SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
`product`.`id` AS `product_id`,
`product`.`shortenUrl` AS `product_shortenUrl`,
`product`.`name` AS `product_name`,
`product`.`price` AS `product_price`,
`product`.`promoPrice` AS `product_promoPrice`,
`product`.`deliveryCost` AS `product_deliveryCost`,
`product`.`promoEndDate` AS `product_promoEndDate`,
`product`.`description` AS `product_description`,
`product`.`amount` AS `product_amount`,
`product`.`photo` AS `product_photo`,
`product`.`width` AS `product_width`,
`product`.`height` AS `product_height`,
`product`.`depth` AS `product_depth`,
`product`.`colorCode` AS `product_colorCode`,
`product`.`created` AS `product_created`,
`product`.`updated` AS `product_updated`,
`product`.`deletedAt` AS `product_deletedAt`,
`product`.`categoryId` AS `product_categoryId`,
`product`.`ordersId` AS `product_ordersId`,
`category`.`id` AS `category_id`,
`category`.`name` AS `category_name`,
`category`.`icon` AS `category_icon`,
`category`.`created` AS `category_created`,
`category`.`updated` AS `category_updated`,
`category`.`deletedAt` AS `category_deletedAt`,
`category`.`groupId` AS `category_groupId`,
`room`.`id` AS `room_id`,
`room`.`shortenUrl` AS `room_shortenUrl`,
`room`.`name` AS `room_name`,
`room`.`icon` AS `room_icon`,
`room`.`created` AS `room_created`,
`room`.`updated` AS `room_updated`,
`room`.`deletedAt` AS `room_deletedAt`
FROM
`product` `product`
LEFT JOIN `category` `category` ON
`category`.`id` = `product`.`categoryId` AND(`category`.`deletedAt` IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN `room_products_product` `room_product` ON
`room_product`.`productId` = `product`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `room` `room` ON
`room`.`id` = `room_product`.`roomId` AND(`room`.`deletedAt` IS NULL)
WHERE
`product`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
ORDER BY
`product`.`name` ASC
```

And it returns duplicated data with diffrent rooms data:

[image]

The data returned to the client looks fine, with no duplicates with the correct link to the rooms, but with incorrect pagination.

How can I paginate correctly in this case? Is this at all possible?

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: GROUP BY all comun that are identical per group and for the rest of the columns choose aggregation functions